# How can I sort jquery-datatable by two columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have one datatable which I created using jQuery. It has five column and I am sorting it by its third column. like this:

```
 "aaSorting": [[2, 'desc']]
```

So, My query is this: If two rows have the same data for column third, then I want to sort those rows by some other column. How can I do that?

Comment: [DataTables multi column and custom sort example](http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/multi_col_sort.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify more than one column with [`aaSorting`](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref) option (DataTables 1.9) or [`order`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/order) option (DataTables 1.10+).

For example:

```
"aaSorting": [[2, 'desc'], [3, 'asc']]
```